# Seperate Sessions in Tabs using geckofx

Tags: c#, session, cookies, geckofx

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application, that functions like a browser. I have standard functionality at adding browser tabs etc.
The main goal i need to achieve is that i have different sessions between tabs.
For the browser framework i use geckofx 45 and xulrunner.
I also assigned the nsICookieManager2 to have more options on using cookies.

This is my code for adding browser to tabs and those to the tabcontrol:

```
private void btn_Tab_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate(txtbx_Url.Text);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.Visible = true;
        tabControl1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top & AnchorStyles.Bottom & AnchorStyles.Right & AnchorStyles.Left;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("newTab"+ (i));
        tabControl1.SelectTab(i);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(browser);          
        i += 1;
```

The Problem with the nsICookieManager2 is that it ignores session cookies from websites. ALthough this is basically the function i want to have but this wouldnt allow reloading/refreshing the browser tab.

Thats the cookiemanger2:

```
    public class CookieServiceFactory : GenericOneClassNsFactory<CookieServiceFactory, CookieService>
{
    public const string ContractID = "@mozilla.org/cookieService;1";
}
public class CookieService : nsICookieManager2
{
    private static nsICookieManager2 _cookieService;

    static CookieService()
    {
        _cookieService = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager2>(Contracts.CookieManager);
    }

    nsISimpleEnumerator nsICookieManager2.GetEnumeratorAttribute()
    {
        return _cookieService.GetEnumeratorAttribute();
    }

    public void Remove(nsAUTF8StringBase aHost, nsACStringBase aName, nsAUTF8StringBase aPath, bool aBlocked)
    {
        _cookieService.Remove(aHost, aName, aPath, aBlocked);
    }

    public void Add(nsAUTF8StringBase aHost, nsAUTF8StringBase aPath, nsACStringBase aName, nsACStringBase aValue, bool aIsSecure, bool aIsHttpOnly, bool aIsSession, long aExpiry)
    {
        _cookieService.Add(aHost, aPath, aName, aValue, aIsSecure, aIsHttpOnly, aIsSession, aExpiry);
    }

    public bool CookieExists(nsICookie2 aCookie)
    {
        return _cookieService.CookieExists(aCookie);
    }

    public uint CountCookiesFromHost(nsAUTF8StringBase aHost)
    {
        return _cookieService.CountCookiesFromHost(aHost);
    }

    public nsISimpleEnumerator GetCookiesFromHost(nsAUTF8StringBase aHost)
    {
        return _cookieService.GetCookiesFromHost(aHost);
    }

    public void ImportCookies(nsIFile aCookieFile)
    {
        _cookieService.ImportCookies(aCookieFile);
    }

    public nsISimpleEnumerator GetCookiesForApp(uint appId, bool onlyBrowserElement)
    {
        return _cookieService.GetCookiesForApp(appId, onlyBrowserElement);
    }

    public void RemoveCookiesForApp(uint appId, bool onlyBrowserElement)
    {
        _cookieService.RemoveCookiesForApp(appId, onlyBrowserElement);
    }

    nsISimpleEnumerator nsICookieManager.GetEnumeratorAttribute()
    {
        return _cookieService.GetEnumeratorAttribute();
    }

    public void RemoveAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me getting the browser to have different sessions in each tab, but allowing to refresh the page on the tab.